# Youtube oauth2 authorization returns redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to access the Youtube API via python so that I can insert videos into a playlist. To do so I have to use  oauth2 to authorize myself. I have looked up many guides and videos and followed their instructions step by step but I always get the same result, saying `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`

The code that I am using is

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets.json", scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'])
flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent')
credentials = flow.credentials
print(credentials.to_json())
```

I have also tried

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets.json", scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'])
flow.run_console()
credentials = flow.credentials
print(credentials.to_json())
```

I understand that this occurs when there is a mismatch between the redirect_uri on the request side and what is listed in the console. But I have triple checked that on https://console.developers.google.com/ I have the redirect URI to be http://localhost.com:8080 and have checked to make sure that my client_secrets.json file reflects the same. I have set my JavaScript origins to also be http://localhost.com:8080. I have set my oauth clientID to be a web application as I am running this in pycharm. However, whenever I run my code I get the same error saying `The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}`

I have looked at the other questions on stackOverflow and have tried the solutions that were suggested but none of them have worked. I have no idea why I cannot get authorization and desperately need help

Comment: I do suspect that you mean `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://localhost.com:8080`.

Comment: Yes. I have tried all different forms of `localhost` and still no luck